# Tips for making choppy video less jarring

Tags: video-quality, effects

I produce a podcast that I also publish to YouTube. It's just two talking heads having an interview.

The recording of my most recent guest came through *very* badly.  The audio sounds fine, but the video averages about 2-3 fps.

I'm looking for tips to make this less noticeable for those watching on YouTube. Most important, I don't want viewers to think they're having connectivity problems while watching the video.

I'm *not* trying to "improve the frame rate"... I'm sure that data is simply lost, and perhaps short of some AI magic, there's nothing to be done.  That's fine.

I'm toying with two ideas:

1. Put the talking heads in a frame, and add a subtle animated background. This way the video is constantly moving, and it will be clear to the viewer that the choppiness is "intentional"
2. Add an animated watermark to accomplish the same goal.

The third, more extreme idea I've had is to just ditch the video entirely, and use a publicity photo of the guest in place, as I've done when I was unable to record video entirely.

Is there anything like a common approach to this sort of problem? Anything else I should consider?

Comment: Only not very helpful suggestion is get them to record locally next time.  It always looks better (assuming you can get them to press record), and then sync it all up afterwards.

Comment: It was recorded locally, with Riverside.fm.  I expect the problem was due to overloaded CPU or something like that.

Comment: Oh no... Separate iPhone next time, just for recording the interview... Laptop for the zoom call...